# What happens when attaching exactly the same NSLayoutConstraints to the same UIView multiple times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

The question says it all. Does it get ignored? Or does it just keep attaching the same constraint multiple times?

Also is there any performance issue if I do this?

I'm asking because the alternative seems to be keep reference to all constraints as they get attached and then later look them up to make this decision. It would be nice if I don't have to implement all this logic.

Comment: What do you mean by 'same constraint' ? Same attributes but different constants or exactly the same?

Comment: I mean "Exactly the same". Otherwise they will keep getting attached and throw conflicts, right?

Comment: Right, unless you disable some of them. Performance wise, it's best to add all of your constraints right away, and apply changes to the layout by enabling and disabling from code. Multiple constraints won't be ignored since you can change any of them at any time. Also, they won't affect performance in any significant way. Why would you add multiple constraints with the exactly same values and attributes?

Comment: @Vlad You should take a look at [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit).  It takes all the pain out of using constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, adding same(same `NSLayoutConstraint` object) constraints again, are ignored.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since i haven't tried it practically but it will create problem if you need any sort of animation.

For example if you need to move your `view` with animation then you will have to change the same sort of constraint multiple time for each identical constraint which brings code pain.

Other than this problem, mutiple identical constraint doesn't really create conflicts but can cause performance issue if you have do this with many views in a single ViewController.